# Return solr response in json format

Tags: java, json, solr, solrj

I am trying to return solr response in JSON format. However I am not able to get the JSON response. Below is my solr config:'

```
<queryResponseWriter name="json" default="true" class="org.apache.solr.request.JSONResponseWriter">
    <str name="content-type">application/json</str>
</queryResponseWriter>
```

Below is my java code:

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(serverUrl);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(query);
query.set("indent","true");
query.set("wt","json");
QueryResponse response = server.query(query);

System.out.println(response.getResults().get(index));
```

However output is displyed in following format.

```
{numFound=1,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{_uniqueKey=[“abc@gmail.com”,”abc”], calculation_policy=text_value, username=abc, email=abc@gmail.com, display_order=10, last_login=Mon Jan 26 11:27:35 PST 2015, created=Mon Jan 26 11:27:35 PST 2015}]}
```

However I get JSON response after execute following line:

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(queryResponse.getResults().get(index)));
```

Can someone please tell me what step am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this link may clarify:
[quoted format json from Solrj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618937/quoted-format-json-from-solrj)

Else maybe you can achieve what you need just through an Http Request as I know that indeed has json support.

Answer (score 6):

With newer versions of Solr (starting with 4.7.0) it is possible to return the query response directly in json-format. This can be done with the `NoOpResponseParser`.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest(query);

NoOpResponseParser rawJsonResponseParser = new NoOpResponseParser();
rawJsonResponseParser.setWriterType("json");
req.setResponseParser(rawJsonResponseParser);

NamedList<Object> resp = mySolrClient.request(req);
String jsonResponse = (String) resp.get("response");

System.out.println(jsonResponse );
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Solrj uses **wt=javabin&version=2** as default for fetching results as described in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/javabin

However to show the response in json either use GSON or Jackson(Object Mapper).